# frida error `TypeError: cannot write property 'implementation' of undefined`

Tags: instrumentation, android-instrumentation, frida

I am trying to inject the below script using frida

```
function main() {
Java.perform(function () {
    let fhs = Java.use("com.tencent.mm.protocal.protobuf.fhs");
    fhs.da.implementation = function (bArr) {
        console.log('da is called' + ', ' + 'bArr: ' + bArr);
        let ret = this.da(bArr);
        console.log('da ret value is ' + ret);
        return ret;
    };
})}setImmediate(main)
```

Throws the below error

```
TypeError: cannot set property 'implementation' of undefined
at <anonymous> (/a.js:11)
at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11)
at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:238)
at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:213)
at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11)
at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:232)
at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:192)
at main (/a.js:12)
at apply (native)
at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/core.js:45)
```

command i am using **frida -U  com.tencent.mm  -l ./Desktop/a.js --no-pause**

Below one is the decompiled code of the apk file.

```
public final fhs da(byte[] bArr) {
    AppMethodBeat.i(2376);
    net.a.a.a.a aVar = new net.a.a.a.a(bArr, unknownTagHandler);
    for (int nextFieldNumber = getNextFieldNumber(aVar); nextFieldNumber > 0; nextFieldNumber = getNextFieldNumber(aVar)) {
        if (!populateBuilderWithField(aVar, this, nextFieldNumber)) {
            aVar.kqf();
        }
    }
    fhs kuW = kuW();
    AppMethodBeat.o(2376);
    return kuW;
}
```

Comment: The error means that Frida was not able to hook the method because the mentioned class does not contain a method named `da`. Are you sure you have decompiled the exact same APK you have installed on the phone?

Comment: I'm sure I've decompiled the exact same APK installed on my phone